# Displaying Bundle values to recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bundle

This is Model Class

```
public class AmountCartModel {

    private String testName;
    private String testPrice;

    public AmountCartModel() {
        this.testName = testName;
        this.testPrice = testPrice;
    }

    public String getTestName() {
        return testName;
    }

    public void setTestName(String testName) {
        this.testName = testName;
    }

    public String getTestPrice() {
        return testPrice;
    }

    public void setTestPrice(String testPrice) {
        this.testPrice = testPrice;
    }
}
```

This Is My Activity

```
public class AmountCartActivity extends AppCompatActivity

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<AmountCartModel> mydataList ;
    private MyAdapter madapter;

    Bundle extras ;
    String testName="";
    String testPrice="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_amount_cart);

        mydataList = new ArrayList<>();
        /*
        * Getting Values From BUNDLE
        * */
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            testName = extras.getString("test_name");
            testPrice = extras.getString("test_price");

            //Just add your data in list
            AmountCartModel mydata = new AmountCartModel();  // object of Model Class
            mydata.setTestName(testName );
            mydata.setTestPrice(testPrice);
            mydataList.add(mydata);
        }

       madapter=new MyAdapter(mydataList);
    madapter.setMyDataList(mydataList);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyler_amount_cart);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);

    }
```

This is My Recycler Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<AmountCartModel> myDataList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        myDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        // Replace with your layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.amount_cart_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Set Your Data here to yout Layout Components..

        // to get Amount
        holder.testName.setText(myDataList.get(position).getTestName());
        holder.testPrice.setText(myDataList.get(position).getTestPrice());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

            return myDataList.size();

    }

    public void setMyDataList(List<AmountCartModel> myDataList) {
        // getting list from Fragment.
        this.myDataList = myDataList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView testName,testPrice;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // itemView.findViewById

            testName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_name_one);
            testPrice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_name);

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Logcat

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.snpinfotech.snp.aoplapp, PID: 11874
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.snpinfotech.snp.aoplapp.aopl.amountCartContent.AmountCartActivity$MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AmountCartActivity.java:374)
                      at com.snpinfotech.snp.aoplapp.aopl.amountCartContent.AmountCartActivity$MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AmountCartActivity.java:343)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2023)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                    at android.

Here i am getting Values From Previous Activity Recycler view And i am trying to display it through Bundle in this Activity.
Problem is 
 that when i am doing it by this approach the activity is displaying me Nothing and i am getting values in my bundle what is the problem i m not getting it  . Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: Forget to set the adapter

Comment: If you spend a couple of minutes on SO you'll find a solution for this.

Comment: already spend hours still unable to solve ..

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you forgot to set adapter.
Change your code

```
madapter=new MyAdapter(mydataList);
madapter.setMyDataList(mydataList);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyler_amount_cart);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

to

```
madapter=new MyAdapter(mydataList);
madapter.setMyDataList(mydataList);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyler_amount_cart);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
```

EDIT 2: Change your onBindViewHolder as:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.testName.setText(myDataList.get(position).getTestName());
    holder.testPrice.setText(myDataList.get(position).getTestPrice());
}
```

EDIT: As just an additional idea, below code does the same as your getItemCount() function does.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myDataList.size();
}
```

Comment: have edited my code with yours now its displaying me test_list_row xml file only @gml

Comment: You should edit your onBindViewHolder too. Wait for an edit ... @Sujal

Comment: holder.testName.setText(myDataList.get(position).getTestName());
            holder.testPrice.setText(myDataList.get(position).getTestPrice());  giving me  java.lang.NullPointerException in these 2 line

Comment: Are you sure R.id.test_name_one and R.id.price_name is included in R.layout.amount_cart_row?

Comment: I am sorry you said test_list_row.xml was shown in your first comment. Did you check amount_cart_row or test_list_row?

Comment: oh my mistake ..yes i have checked amount_card_row

Comment: if the problem is not solved still, can you send full exception log?

Comment: Please check my edited question i have posted the exception log

Comment: can you check if holder or holder.testName is null?

Comment: ya its null and  its giving me size 1 position 0  and no parent

Comment: Size and position are correct. Which one is null, holder or holder.testName?

Comment: holder.testPrice is giving me null

Comment: The problem must be about ids then. Please check amount_card_row again or share it here.

Comment: Ok will check and let you know.i will post it tomorrow as I am leaving my work place .thank you

Comment: ya bro you are right there is some problem in my id and i fixed it and its working fine.thank you . @glm